# Как делать красивый GUI на языке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как делать красивый и современный дизайн приложений на питоне? Можно ли использовать html и сss для дизайна в PyQt?

Comment: PyQt есть для этого QML

Comment: 1 - выбрать GUI библиотеку, сделать красивый и современный интерфейс средствами выбранной библиотеки.

Answer (score 3):

Тоже недавно задался этим вопросом. Выбор пал на [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/). Аргументы за - кроссплатформенность, выглядит органично на всех платформах, так как использует родной стиль элементов ОС. Сам пока читаю [перевод](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/WxPythonInAction) WxPython in Action. Если кто-то может посоветовать хорошую литературу, буду благодарен.